# Output difference of OR and UNION in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In which cases, the output of using `OR` and `UNION` differs in SQL?
I know in some situations using one of them is more efficient in terms of processing time than the other...
[Time efficiency difference ][1]

**But in which cases output of OR and UNION is different?**

1

```
Select c, d from T 
Where c = 'c1' OR d < 'd1';
```

2

```
select c, d from T 
Where c = 'c1'
UNION 
Select c, d from T 
Where d < 'd1';
```

Comment: Uhhh . . . `OR` is a boolean operator used to combine boolean expressions. `UNION` is a set-based operator used to combine subqueries.  The two are not similar at all.  So your question does not make sense.

Comment: May be you are talking about `union` vs `union all`?

Comment: I added a query example to my question .

Comment: Where the output is logically different, pick the one that is correct. When the two are logically the same, trust the optimizer to create the same plan for both, unless or until you have evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/union-or-sql-server-queries/) you had posted gave examples and results. If you notice, the row counts are the same for each example. This means the outputs were the same.

Comment: But as far as I know, in some special cases, their output is different.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of which records meet the criteria, the two versions are identical. However, they differ in how duplicates are handled and may also differ in terms of sort order. `UNION ALL` is different again in terms of duplicates.

Let's begin by convincing ourselves the same set of records match the criteria for each version, using your own examples:

```
--Call this Query 1 (or Q1)
Select c, d from T 
Where
--The following line is the "first disjunct"
c = 'c1'
OR
--While this is the "second disjunct"
d < 'd1';
```

and

```
--Call this Query 2 (or Q2)
--Call this Query 2 part A (Q2a)
select c, d from T 
Where c = 'c1'
UNION 
--Call this Query 2 part B (Q2b)
Select c, d from T 
Where d < 'd1';
```

### Why `UNION` matches the same records as `OR`

Consider the following table, which exhausts all the possibilities with respect to the where clauses and first and second disjuncts.

```
| Row | Disjunct / Where clause |         Returned By         | 
|  #  |  c = 'c1'  |  d < 'd1'  |  Q1  |  Q2a  |  Q2b  |  Q2  | 
|-------------------------------------------------------------|    
|     |     A      |     B      |  W   |   X   |   Y   |  Z   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|  R1 |   TRUE     |   TRUE     |  Yes |  Yes  |  Yes  |  Yes |
|  R2 |   TRUE     |   FALSE    |  Yes |  Yes  |  No   |  Yes |
|  R3 |   FALSE    |   TRUE     |  Yes |  No   |  Yes  |  Yes |
|  R4 |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |  No  |  No   |  No   |  No  |
```

(If the fields c or d are `NULL` then the comparisons will be treated as false, so it is not necessary to consider `NULL` separately.)

- Q1 finds all and only those rows where either column A or column B is
  true.
- Q2a finds all and only those rows where column A is true.
- Q2b finds all and only those rows where column B is true.
- Q3 finds all and only those rows found by either or both Q2a or
  Q2b.

As you can see, column W reads the same as column Z, which is to say that Q1 finds a row if and only if it is also found by Q2.

### How `UNION` and `UNION ALL` differ from `OR`

Firstly, because the database engine is not being instructed to sort the records in your example, it is likely to return the records in a different order.

Secondly, the `OR`, `UNION` and `UNION ALL` versions differ in their treatment of duplicates:

1. `OR`: Returns all the records which match the criteria, neither adding nor removing duplicates
2. `UNION`: Returns all the records which match the criteria, but removing any duplicates
3. `UNION ALL`: Returns all the records which match the criteria, with the possibility of returning some records on both sides of the `UNION` and therefore creating duplicates.

This may be illustrated using the following data
(also available here - [rextester.com/BLNTJT55740](http://rextester.com/BLNTJT55740)):

```
create table UnionVsOr
(
    id int primary key,
    c varchar(5),
    d varchar(5),
    Notes varchar(100)
)
insert into UnionVsOr
values (1,  'c1', 'd0', 'Meets both criteria, possible duplicate (1)' ),
       (2,  'c1', 'd0', 'Meets both criteria, possible duplicate (2)' ),
       (3,  'c1', 'dX', 'Meets first criteria'),
       (4,  'cX', 'd0', 'Meets second criteria'),
       (5,  'cX', 'dX', 'Meets neither criteria')
```

The `OR`, `UNION` and `UNION ALL` queries return the following datasets respectively ...

```
  | c   | d
------------
1 | c1  | d0   
2 | c1  | d0 --duplicate of row above retained
3 | c1  | dX
4 | cX  | d0

  | c   | d
------------
1 | c1  | d0 --duplicate removed
2 | c1  | dX
3 | cX  | d0

  | c   | d
------------
1 | c1  | d0
2 | c1  | d0 --duplicate of row above retained
3 | c1  | dX
4 | c1  | d0
5 | c1  | d0 --duplcates added as returned by both Q2a and Q2b
6 | cX  | d0
```

There is no answer to the question of which of these results is correct. They are each doing different things, and the user should select the one which gives the right result for their use-case.

Comment: The `OR` version can still return duplicates if there are multiple rows with common `c` and `d` values. The `UNION` variant will not. You can only assert that they'll be the same if the `OR` variant uses `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Good point @damien_the_unbeliever. I'll update my answer when time allows.